# Getting output of a c file into a bash variable

Tags: c, bash

I have a c file that checks whether there is a ! in the argument given (ie ./a.out hi!) and return 0 if it does and 1 if it doesn't, which works as it's supposed to.

I need to make a bash shell file (.sh) that uses the c file to check if files in a directory contain the character, ie. if the directory has dogs!.sh fly!.c ring.txt, executing ./script.sh should return

```
dogs!.sh
fly!.c
```

But I have no idea how to do so?
Can anybody help out?

Comment: I think you left an extraneous `}` in your c file, right by the `else` statement. Your `if` block doesn't use a bracket, so when it reaches that next one it thinks you're ending the `main()` routine.

Answer (score 3):

Your compile line:

```
gcc includes.c
```

Will produce an output program called `a.out`. You need to run *that* command, not try to execute your C source as a shell script, which is what your current script is doing.  Example:

```
ret=$(./a.out ${file})
```

You don't need the `ret`, though, since your program has no output. Just check the exit value.

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
```

Editorial note: this answer assumes that you've copy/pasted something wrong when asking this question, since your error message shows `alpha.c`, but that's not mentioned anywhere else. And that you fix the syntax errors in your C program, too!

Comment: You can also check the return value directly `if a.out "$file"`...